# implement AVL-Tree in C without return-functions

Tags: c, pointers, rotation, avl-tree

I need to implement an AVL-Tree in C with the following signatures. It is not possible to add "returns" in the given functions, as this might be part of the exercise. So I have to find a solution with the given void-functions. My Problem is the case, when a subtree rotates around a node x/y, then x/y is not the root of the subtree anymore. But due to the functions are void, I cannot return the "new root of subtree". Here are some details:

insert function with recursive helping-function:

```c
/* helping function to walk recursively through the tree, create node, update height and balance */
Node* insertRecursive(Tree* tree, Node* root, Node* parent, int value) {
    
    /* create node if subnode does not exist */
    if(!root) {
        Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        [...]
        return newNode;
    }
    
    /* recursive walk, update height, balance */
    [...]

    balance(tree, root);
    
    return root;
}

void insertValue(Tree *tree, int value) {
    tree->root = insertRecursive(tree, tree->root, NULL, value);
}
```

balance function, which calls the rotations.

```c
void balance(Tree* tree, Node* node) {

    /* getHeight-calls to calculate the heights of subtrees */
    [...]

    /* if-statements to find out, how to rotate */
    [...]
    
    /* a rotation call, where the problem might occur. 
     * It think, after the rotation, "node" should be the new root of the subtree.
     * similar to: node = rotateLeft(tree, node), if there had been a return-statement. */
    rotateLeft(tree, node);
}
```

leftRotation(tree, node) where node->value = 3

```
  2                       2
 / \                     / \
1   3(x)                1   4(y)
     \                     / \
      4(y)             (x)3   5
       \
        5              

before rotation        after rotation:
```

The tree looks fine. How can I tell the caller, that "node" is now "4" and not "3" anymore?

```c
void rotateLeft(Tree* tree, Node* x) {
    Node *y = x->right;
    x->right = y->left;
    y->left = x;
    
    if(y->left)
        y->left->parent = x;
    
    y->parent = x->parent;
    
    if(tree->root == x) {
        tree->root = y;
    } else if(x == x->parent->left)
        x->parent->left = y;
    else x->parent->right = y;
    y->left = x;
    x->parent = y;
    
    x->height = 1 + max(getHeight(x->left), getHeight(x->right));
    y->height = 1 + max(getHeight(y->left), getHeight(y->right));
}
```

given function signatures:

```c
void leftRotate(Tree* tree, Node* x);
void rightRotate(Tree* tree, Node* y);
void balance(Tree* tree, Node* node);
void insertValue(Tree *tree, int value)
```

given structs:

```c
struct Node {
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
    struct Node* parent;
    int value;
    int height;
};

struct Tree {
    struct Node* root;
    int numberOfNodes;
};
```

What I have tried so far: I tried to find out, how I could modify the "original" pointer, when calling the function, like:

```c
balance(tree, node) {
    [...]
    leftRotate(tree, &node); /* which is compiler error */
```

or:

```c
    leftRotate(tree, &(*node)); /* which works but doesn't solve */
```

or:

```
    Node tmp = node;
    leftRotate(tree, &tmp); /* doesn't solve, because other pointers now point to tmp in stack */
    *node = *tmp;
```

or:

```
    leftRotate(tree, node);
    node = node->parent; /* when a rotation happens, node is always (??) the parent of node. Worked in some cases but not when calling balance in the insert function, where it is not clear if a rotations happend or not. */
```

I also tried to use a temporary tree struct for each balance call, but then I couldn't update the parents, as there are no parents in the tree struct.

```
Node* insertRecursive(Tree* tree, Node* root, Node* parent, int value) {
    [...]
    Tree tmp;
    tmp.root = node;
    balance(&tmp, tmp.root);
    node = tmp;
```

Comment: So you may need to update the root of the tree, but you have no way of telling the caller the new root. You have a parent link, but this may point nowhere for the root of the whole tree. Did I get your problem correctly? Another option: swap `value`s between nodes.

Comment: It seems `tree` has a `root` member. Why do you need to update `node` if you can just look at `tree->root`?

Comment: I added a little drawing to my text. Maybe it makes it a bit clearer. When I call ```balance(tree, tree->root)```it is fine. But when I call it deeper inside of the tree, let's say ```balance(tree, node)```, where node is a subtree, then the problem occurs. Or did I understood the AVL concept wrong and balance is always applied as ```balance(tree, tree->root)``` in every step of the recursion?

Comment: @teapot418 provided one technique of copying values. But, another technique is to create a temporary *`tree`* that holds *`node`* as the root.

Comment: (1) I don't understand exactly where and which values could be copied? After rotation?  Copy the whole pointer-content ```*node1 = *node2``` or how do you mean?

Comment: (2) When I create a temporary ```Tree tmp``` for the subtree and rotate on it, I will run into the problem, that I have to reconnect the parent-pointers. ```y->parent = x->parent```. But ```tmp.root``` does not have a parent. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: `insertRecursive` has the `parent`.